# How do I call my function that contains a completion handler?

Tags: swift2, alamofire, swifty-json

Still trying to get the hang of completions handlers as the majority of my application uses rest api calls that are async.  My project uses `Alamofire` and `SwiftyJSON` I have a class function that accepts parameters that I want to use to call my `POST` api and insert values into a database.  The API returns the ID of the new row inserted.  I want to get the response as a swifty `JSON` object returned from the function.  Here is the function:

```
class func insertItem(item: String, description: String, quantityOnHand: Int, reorderPoint: Int, supplier_id:Int, completionHandler: JSON -> Void) {

    let urlEndpoint = Constants.Urls.Inventory.Add
    let newItem = ["item": item, "description": description, "quantityOnHand": quantityOnHand, "reorderPoint": reorderPoint, "supplier_id": supplier_id]

    Alamofire.request(.POST, urlEndpoint, parameters: (newItem as! [String : AnyObject]), encoding: .JSON)
        .responseJSON { response in
            guard response.result.error == nil else {
                //got an error, need to handle it
                print(response.result.error!)
                return
            }

            completionHandler(JSON(response.response!))
    }

}
```

I'm trying to call this function but I'm not sure what to put for the completion parameter:

```
Inventory.insertItem("NewFromFunc", description: "new function!!!", quantityOnHand: 400, reorderPoint: 1, supplier_id: 2, completionHandler: ???)
    }
```

EDIT: Updated function as it is now. Can't return anything after completion:

```
    func insertItem(item: String, description: String, quantityOnHand: Int, reorderPoint: Int, supplier_id:Int, completionHandler: (JSON) -> Void) {

        let urlEndpoint = "http://url"
        let newItem = ["item": item, "description": description, "quantityOnHand": quantityOnHand, "reorderPoint": reorderPoint, "supplier_id": supplier_id]

        Alamofire.request(.POST, urlEndpoint, parameters: ((newItem) as! [String : AnyObject]))
            .responseJSON { response in
                //print(newItem)

                guard response.result.error == nil else {
                    //got an error, need to handle it
                    print("Error thread")

                    return
                }
                if let value: AnyObject = response.result.value {
                    //hande results as JSON without bunch of nested if loops
                    let statusCode = response.response?.statusCode
                    if statusCode == 201 {

                        //let newid = value["id"]
                        //let status = value["status"]

                        print("Status is 201")
                        print(value)
                    }
                    else {
                        print("there's an issue returning data")
                    }
                }
                completionHandler(JSON(response.response!))
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the type for the completion handler.  Your's apears to have a param of type JSON so somethign like this

```
completionHandler: (JSON) -> Void
```

To make it optional, you would do something like this

```
completionHandler: ((JSON) -> Void)?
```

You would then make your call like so

```
Inventory.insertItem("NewFromFunc", description: "new function!!!", quantityOnHand: 400, reorderPoint: 1, supplier_id: 2){ data in 
    //Do something with the data object
}
```

This can also be accomplished by creating a typeAlias if you are going to have multiple methods that have the same typed handlers etc

Here is an example of how I have it in my rest client class using typealias since the response is used for multiple methods

```
typealias ServiceResponse = (JSON, NSError?) -> Void

class RESTClient : NSObject {
    static let sharedInstance = RESTClient()

    func makeRequest(type: String, endPoint: String, parameters: [String: AnyObject]?, onCompletion: ServiceResponse){
        makeRequest(type, endPoint: endPoint, parameters: parameters, files: nil, onCompletion: onCompletion)
    }
...
```

Comment: But how can I get the JSON returned by the function when I call it?  Is it stored in the `data` variable? I've tried grabbing it with `data["id"]` but nothing works.  The function was suppose to return the JSON data.  Adding the completion handler caused me to change it to return void.  How can I return the data? Thank you!

Comment: Depending on the type of value you should be able to do something like data["id"].string. This will return a nullable of string. If you are sure it is not null you can use stringValue which will unwrap it. There are these methods for various types (int, number, bool etc)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new class

import UIKit

typealias ServiceResponse = (NSDictionary!, NSError!) -> Void

class AFNInjector: NSObject {

```
func getDataWith(parameters:NSDictionary, url:String, onCompletion: ServiceResponse) -> Void {

    let manager:AFHTTPRequestOperationManager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()
    let serializer:AFJSONRequestSerializer = AFJSONRequestSerializer()
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = NSSet(objects:"text/html") as NSSet as Set<NSObject>
    manager.requestSerializer = serializer
    manager.POST(url, parameters: parameters, success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, responsobject: AnyObject?) -> Void in
        let data = responsobject as! NSDictionary?
        onCompletion(data,nil)
    }) { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        let errorObject = error as NSError?
        onCompletion(nil,errorObject)
    }
}
```

}

After that you can call this

```
    let Obj=AFNInjector()
    let parameters:NSDictionary = ["apicall":"Login","password":txtPassword.text,"email":txtEmail.text]

   Obj.getDataWith(parameters, url:BASEURL) { (result, error) -> Void in
        if (result != nil){


            print(result)


           }
        else{



        }
    }
```